# IO#ioctl mangling an argument ? (Ruby 2.1.3)

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.1

It seems [`IO#ioctl`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-i-ioctl) alters 2nd argument passed.

```
require "socket"

SIOCGIWESSID      = 0x8B1B
IW_ESSID_MAX_SIZE = 32

sock = Socket.new(Socket::AF_INET, Socket::SOCK_DGRAM, 0)
template = "a16pI2"
iwessid  = [ 'wlan0', ' ' * IW_ESSID_MAX_SIZE, IW_ESSID_MAX_SIZE, 1 ].pack(template)

iwessid_bak = iwessid.dup
p iwessid == iwessid_bak    # true

sock.ioctl(SIOCGIWESSID, iwessid)  # iwessid string changed after #ioctl

p iwessid == iwessid_bak    # false !
p iwessid, iwessid_bak      # iwessid is different, lot of zero chars \0x00
                            # appended to original content
```

Is this an intended behavior or a bug ?
Tested with new Ruby 2.1.3 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is intended behaviour, how else would you get the data you are interested in?

Ruby’s `IO#ioctl` is a fairly thin wrapper around the platforms own `ioctl` system call. This system call (or its C wrapper) accepts an integer option and a pointer to a data structure (i.e. a struct) relevant to that option, which contains the data into or out of the kernel (it can also accept an integer for some options). So you set up the struct, make the `ioctl` call with a pointer to that struct as an argument, then examine the changes in it to get the information you’re after.

Ruby allows you to pass this struct as a Ruby string, but it still needs to be in the format expected by the system call, hence you usually need to use `pack`. You likely need to use `unpack` on the same string afterwards to extract the data you need.

I don’t know anything about the `SIOCGIFHWADDR` option, but a quick search comes up with a [mailing list thread](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/195655) that seems to be using the same (or similar) example to yours. In that the code continues after the `ioctl` call with:

```
interface, essid, len, flags = iwreq.unpack("a16pII")
```

Whilst the details aren’t exactly the same (the `unpack` format is slightly different and they’ve used a different variable name) it shows how you would go about getting the result you’re after.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would just expect argument passed to a method by value will be left untouched (except indirectly like in case of Array elements). Duping should be performed internally inside #ioctl and retrieved data and return value as a method's result. Consider strongly uncanonical to Ruby.

Comment: @DavidUnric I agree it’s very unusual Ruby, but is fairly common for C code. `IO#ioctl` seems to be trying to follow the underlying `ioctl` closely. Some calls do return useful info in the int return value. As far as I understand, `ioctl` is pretty low level and platform specific, even when writing C. I suspect it would be tricky to get a general Ruby like interface to it.

Comment: Ok. I'm marking your answer as accepted, because you were right it's an intentional behavior. `IO#ioctl` method's signature by the documentation returns just an integer (retcode) and no resulting data from request, so there is no ambiguousness where can be stored.